# Не могу авторизоваться post-запросом, помогите!

Tags: python, post, авторизация, requests

*Прошу помощи!*
Пытаюсь пройти авторизацию, но не получается.
Я просто отправляю post с параметрами при помощи requests.
Что я делаю не так?

```
import requests
with requests.Session() as session:
    url = "https://www.domestika.org"
    url_login = url + "/auth/login?locale=en"
    params = {
        'utf8': True,
        'authenticity_token': 'fHTpfC8omfxKSd9e8Y21q/En468tsUtp0XYSrY5c2zB/KC/POX6fBMW5Oltl8mkM4E1L+W6HbmKQJz8upaOSEA==',
        'user[remember_me]': 1,
        'user[email]': 'te5tqaz@yandex.ru',
        'user[password]': 'te5tqazte5tqaz',
        'button': ''
    }
    response_auth = session.post(url_login, params=params)

    # Ниже строка для отладки
    with open('output_post.html', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
        f.write(response_post.text)
```

Вот такой использую код, но залогиниться при этом не получается.

**Почта и аккаунт - все тестовое, создал только что, так что можно на них эксперементировать.**

[image: Скриншот инструментов разработчика]

Comment: Попробуйте перед авторизацией сделать просто запрос на ресурс, чтобы получить от него куки.

Comment: Да, я так уже делал. И добавлял различные заголовки, но не помогает...

Comment: Измучался, все равно не получается...

Comment: authenticity_token откуда берёте? И почему-то на скрине в form data почта только до собачки